# Security aspects of Civicrm SMS API functionality

Tags: developer, sms, civisms

We are aiming to implement SMS messaging in the UK Research environment

We are concerned about the Information Governance and Data Security aspects of SMS messaging, and are therefore interested in the precise data transmitted and received by the API call from Civicrm.

Would be most grateful if anyone could provide an overview of the SMS functionality within Civicrm, including how to debug GET/POST data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use SMS you need to install an extension corresponding to the telco provider providing the service. So it depends on the extension, but in general there's just 4 pieces of data that get sent: authentication credentials, the FROM number, the TO number, and the message.

You can see for example the Twilio one is here: https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.sms.twilio/blob/494728cf13bb65c228429665c158d899cd7e6dc1/org_civicrm_sms_twilio.php#L163-L169.